# When running rails server as daemon, do I need to set cache_classes to true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, server, configuration, daemon

I want to run rails server as daemon so other people can keep accessing the server when I'm away.

But if I start it with `rails s -d`, and have `config.cache_classes = false`, then I get the following error:

`uninitialized constant Template::TemplateScope`

The `TemplateScope` here is is a `module` that `extend ActiveSupport::Concern`

And `Template` is a normal `class` that `include TemplateScope`

However, if I start `rails s -d` with `config.cache_classes = true`, it works fine.

From [rails documentation about configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration), it says:

> config.cache_classes controls whether or not application classes and modules should be reloaded on each request. Defaults to false in development mode, and true in test and production modes.

This means in this case stopping reloading on every request fixed the problem, but that doesn't make sense: Why would stop reloading on every request fixes the problem? It shouldn't matter as long as resources are loaded. Is there something I don't know that's happening?

I run `rails s` without the daemon option and with `config.cache_classes = false` too and it works fine. So that means the daemon is causing the problem.

However, I don't know where to find the documentation for daemon, so I came here to ask if any one know what's going on, because I'm struggling to understand. Please point me to the documentation if you know where it is too.

Comment: what is TemplateScope, how do you load it ?

Comment: I didn't write the code, I think they load it by `include TemplateScope`. You can see the code here: https://github.com/DMPRoadmap/roadmap

Comment: Template scope is a module

Comment: try changing that line to `include ::TemplateScope`

Comment: What does the `::` prefix do?

Comment: Its just saying that `TemplateScope` should be resolved at the root level not under `Template` model

Comment: The prefix doesn't help but I have made some progress in my question update 1. Do you know why Update 1 solves the problem?

Comment: no idea why behaves that way in daemon mode, it should be turned off for dev env as per the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

Comment: I have removed update 1 and completely update the question